# Error while trying to read .data file in R

Tags: r, read.table

I am trying to read car.data file at this location - https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data using read.table as below. Tried various solutions listed earlier, but did not work. I am using Windows 8, R version 3.2.3. I can save this file as txt file and then read, but not able to read the .data file directly from URL or even after saving using read.table

```
t <- read.table(
    "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data", 
    fileEncoding="UTF-16", 
    sep = ",", 
    header=F
)
```

Here is the error I am getting and is resulting in an empty dataframe with single cell with "?" in it:

**Warning messages:**

*1: In read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",  :  invalid input found on input connection 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data'*

*2: In read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data'*

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `read.table` when the data is not stored in a table. Data at that link is clearly presented in comma-separated format. Use the RCurl package instead and read the data as CSV:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data")
y <- read.csv(text = x)
```

Now `y` contains your data.

Comment: `read.csv` can read `https` these days, so you don't need the `RCurl` dependency any more

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, thanks for your answer, but it's not working.. getURL threw another error for me: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE): SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087927/cory), here is the solution - just use read.csv directly:

> x <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data")